# How to make the underlay layer clickable while maintaining the scrollability (and clickability) of the overlay layer?

Tags: html, css

I come from Android background and this is almost default behavior in app but I can't seem to achieve it on web. Basically, the underlay height equals the inner height of browser while the overlay is a very long list placed just below the underlay.

I need the underlay to stay in the same place(absolute?) and can be clicked through before the overlay scroll up and cover it. Applying `pointer-events: none;` to the overlay disables any interaction with it but I don't know how to make the underlay clickable otherwise.

Comment: Isn't it counterintuitive to be able to click an element that is covered by another element? What would be the result of such an interaction? Can you provide more details or a reduced example with some code?

Comment: https://www.rezo-zero.com/en
closest to what I want to achieve, it's not covered 100% at first